# convert complex/nested json object to excel table

Tags: angular

I've got a nested json object. For the sake of simplicity:

```
data = {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': {'nestedKey1': 3, 'nestedKey2': 4}}
```

A real object is bigger but the point is that it's a nested one. Values may be strings, numbers or other objects.
Now I need to get an excel table that (for this specific json would look like this):

```
|----------------------------------------
| key1 | key2 |           key3          |
|      |      |--------------------------
|      |      | nestedKey1 | nestedKey2 |
|----------------------------------------
|  1   |  2   |     3      |      4     |
|----------------------------------------
```

Other formats are also acceptable. But this one is most preferable. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert [online](http://convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm)(don't know the size limit they allow)

Although it is not exactly in the same format you expect but it is very much similar, you can do little bit of modification from the output you get here.
Here is a sample screenshot of the output I got when I inserted your json.
[image]

**Stackoverflow**

If you want to write a Service on your own then you can refer to this question on [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892885/javascript-json-to-excel-file-download/52948276). It is something similar to what you want and it is written in JavaScript.

**JQuery**

Here is a JQuery script on this [page](https://www.freakyjolly.com/create-and-download-xsl-excel-from-json-response-data-in-webpage/) for converting JSON to excel.

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx)

Comment: No, I can't do that, I need to write a service that does just that. I tried using 'xlsx' but I can't figure out how to make it write the table in the right format

Comment: You need to write it in which language. I mean which tools and framework are you working on ?

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot to mention it. The framework is angular, the language is typescript.

Comment: @GoBear Ihave updated my answer have a look at the stackblitz example. I think that should be sufficient for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I have written a python package that you can use to convert complex json into excel. https://github.com/akritianand/JsonToExcel