# How to change data display in excel from horizontal to vertical using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xlsx

Referring to this [Javascript JSON to Excel file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892885/javascript-json-to-excel-file-download?noredirect=1&lq=1), I tried and successfully convert from JSON to XLSX. However the result is viewed in horizontal, the question is how to make it vertical? I just have only 1 long object data not multiple object. That why I prefer the result is in vertical for better view.

Horizontal View

[image]

Vertical View

[image]

Code:

```
var data = [{
    "Name": "Michael",
    "Place": "Home",
    }
]

filename='personal.xlsx'; 
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
var wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "People");
XLSX.writeFile(wb,filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have object there, the only thing you need is to pivot it.
this plugin may help you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-pivot-json